# MVC 3 forms Authentication multiple database role Tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication

I am going to use a single LOGIN database (Sql forms authenication) to hold the user information, the user profile information, the available databases for a user (including all available databases for a particular client), and a user's settings/preferences. But I need to have seperate role tables in seperate databases so that when a user logs on to the first database and selects which database to connect to then the roles that user is assigned to is determined by the Database that they connect to. The roles may vary depending on the database and can vary from database to another. The database schemas will be identical for each connected database. What would be your suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to implement a custom `RoleProvider` that internally uses a stock `SqlRoleProvider` initialized with the correct connection string for the user's *current* database.

Comment: Would you know of an example of this? I think you are correct but the how to isn't clear to me at htis point. Thaanks!

Answer (score 1):

The single login database to hold user information should have a table of roles for each database. I am not sure where you want to put the logic for which role has access to what in each database. If you wanted to put it in a database then they should go in their respective databases. The user information should contain which roles the user has access to in each table through a junction table.

```
User
----
UserId
Name

UserRoles
---------
UserRolesId
UserId
AllRolesId

AllRoles
--------
AllRolesId
DatabaseName
RoleName
```